How do i add muliple Fonts in react-quill?
I am trying to add multiple fonts but all of them are replaced by the san serif at the editor, anybody can help?
 const modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: [
        [{ header: "1" }, { header: "2" }, { font: [
          "sans-serif", "serif", "monospace", 
          "Arial", "Courier New", "Georgia", 
          "Times New Roman", "Verdana", "Inter", 
          "Poppins", "Ubuntu", "Roboto", "Cursive", 
          "Lato", "Open Sans", "Montserrat", 
          "Source Sans Pro", "Nunito", "Raleway", 
          "Roboto Condensed"
        ] }],
        [{ size: [] }],
        ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
        [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
        ["link", "video"],
        ["clean"],
      ],
    },
  };

How it looks on end:
Editor View
I am trying to get multiple fonts options available for the user.
